# Which AlertView Button should i put in "cancel"

Tags: ios, uialertview, hig

I have little knowledge regarding the Apple HIG on AlertViews.
Which Button should I put on the left side of my alert view?

[image]

"Skip" will continue on the login process.
"Change" will let the user change his/her password.

Please help me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from Apple's HIG for alerts:

> When the most likely button performs a nondestructive action, it should be on the right in a two-button alert. The button that cancels this action should be on the left.
>
> When the most likely button performs a destructive action, it should be on the left in a two-button alert. The button that cancels this action should be on the right.

So, I would assume that the most likely button is skip especially Skip is in bold in your screenshot (although you may think differently), which is nondestructive. Then, it should be on the right, and change will be on the left.

Find more here: [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Temporary Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think Put the **change Button on the left**,like uninstall a app,the system will create a alert like this,skip in your alert is much like cancel int the screenshot

[image]